# How to turn on highlighting opening/closing tags in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tags, highlight

I have to move from Notepad ++ to Visual and I can't find anywhere how to turn this option on. I'm using it for xml/xml schemes right now.

[Thought fonts and colors would solve my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdLAm.png)

[These options also not helping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/627Ka.png)

Comment: What do you mean: show in a different colour or change when text cursor in the tag?

Comment: In notepad for example if I move my cursor on tag <xsd:sequence> it changes background of tag </xsd:sequance> but it would be fine if it just changed color of the text not whole backgroud. It doesn't really matter, i just need something to point me to closing tag :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlighting start/end tags when text cursor is in one of them is not supported natively in Visual Studio.

There are extensions which do this. For instance [Viasfora](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/19609469-380e-4fcf-bcde-e31caeb658b2).

Comment: Is there a way to make this highlight brighter/change its color?

Comment: @Rafal don't know. It has lots of options…

Comment: Ok! Thank you for help :)